# Variable used without being initialized (queueing)

Tags: c, queue, jobs

I want to make a queue that takes in multiple inputs until they detect "done" then it stops.

So its like the input is:

```
Pea 1
Pork 2
Cheese 4
done
```

And then it returns to menu. Heres my code. The problem is that i get the error "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'myJob' is being used without being initialized." Any idea why that might be? Thanks!

```
void multqueue(struct pqueue *pq, struct job myJob) {
    struct job temp;
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter a name and save its priority: \n");
    scanf("%s", &myJob.name);
    if (strcmp (myJob.name , "done") == 1){
        return;}
    scanf("%d", &myJob.priority);

    if (pq->front == -1) {
        pq->front = 0;
    }
    pq->end++;
    pq->node[pq->end] = myJob;
    for (i = pq->front; i < pq->end; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= pq->end; j++) {

            // Prioritising the queue nodes by comparing priority
            if (pq->node[i].priority > pq->node[j].priority) {
                temp = pq->node[i];
                pq->node[i] = pq->node[j];
                pq->node[j] = temp;
            } else  if (pq->node[i].priority ==
                pq->node[j].priority) {
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using - that will help get them to the right people who can answer them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us the data structure, but these two lines are self-inconsistent:

```
scanf("%s", &myJob.name);
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") == 1)
```

If the `strcmp()` call is correct, then you should only be passing `myJob.name` to `scanf()`.  You don't put the `&` in front of the name of an array of characters.  If the argument passed to `scanf()` as `&myJob.name` is correct, then you should be reading a single character (`%c`).

The runtime warning message is interesting; most systems don't provide that level of protection. I can see that it might be confused by the address of the array being passed. The confusion lies in the fact that the types of `&myJob.name` and `myJob.name` are different, even though the values of the addresses are the same.

You should be testing whether `scanf()` is successful:

```
if (scanf("%s", myJob.name) != 1)
    ...oops — error of some sort...
```

If you type 'Computer Programmer', the job name will only be 'Computer'.

Also, there's no guarantee that `strcmp()` will ever return 1.  It returns 0 if the strings are equal; it returns an undefined positive number if the first string comes after the second when sorted, and an undefined negative number if the first string comes before the second when sorted. The valid comparisons, therefore, are:

```
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") == 0)  // name == done
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") != 0)  // name != done
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") >= 0)  // name >= done
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") <= 0)  // name <= done
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") >  0)  // name >  done
if (strcmp(myJob.name, "done") <  0)  // name <  done
```